# UV Grid appearing as solid colour

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I wanted to create a UV grid for my retopologized meshes, but whenever I add the UV image (obj mode > material properties > base colour >  new image, 512x512px > alpha checked > UV grid), turn viewport shading to texture, the UV grid appears as one solid black colour. I wondered if this was a problem with the scale of the image, but after trying a few different dimensions it is still the same.

Does anyone know what could be the issue? I've attached an image to show the problem:

[image: UV grids showing as solid colour]

Comment: In the _Viewport Shading_ mode _Texture_ which you are using, the object needs a material that uses the image texture you want to display **and** it should be selected in the _Shader Editor_, because if you have different image textures in the material you can switch the visibility between them by selecting them.

Answer (score 2):

First of all make sure that the object is UV unwrapped so that the image texture can be shown correctly on the object - but if you do not know how to unwrap, this would be the topic for another question.

Let us assume the model is UV unwrapped. To show the image texture in the *Viewport Shading* mode *Texture*, it is necessary that the object has a material on it which contains one or more *Image Texture* nodes.

In the following example, the object has a material with three texture nodes: two *Image Texture* nodes, one with a color grid and another with a grey uv grid and the third is a *Noise Texture*. Only the color grid is connected to the *Base Color* of the *Principled BSDF*.

If you now select the *Image Texture* node with the color grid **or** that node was the last **texture node** selected (so it doesn't matter if you have deselected everything afterwards or maybe selected the *BSDF* node) then the viewport will show the color grid texture:

[image: first image texture selected]

If you now select the other *Image Texture* node with the grey UV grid, the viewport will display this one (and still show it after deselecting). It does not matter that the *Image Texture* node is not connected to anything - this mode is for previewing what you select, so to see different images on the object you do not really have to switch the node connections:

[image: second image texture selected]

It is no problem to select the *Principled BSDF* or the *Material Output* node or others after selecting the *Image Texture* node, the image will still be showing. **However**, if you select another texture node that is not an image but **procedural**, like *Noise Texture*, *Voronoi Texture*, *Gradient Texture* etc., these textures will **not** be displayed in the viewport. Instead the object will show the *Color* which is set in the material under *Viewport Display* (by default white or light grey rather, in this case green to clearly show it):

[image: procedural texture selected]

The same happens with materials that do not have any *Image Texture* at all. In this case there is no image which could be shown in *Texture* shading mode, so the *Viewport Display* > *Color* will be visible:

[image: no image textures]