# I've combined two different textures using colour mixing but they're not showing together

Tags: uv, shaders

I'm trying to put the bear logo on my jacket's sleeve. I put the UV maps of the jacket (UVMap) and logo (UVMap.001) in the shading and mix them together. Also, I added a new UV map and unwrapped part of the jacket for the logo. However, they couldn't mix together in the flat viewpoint shading.

When I select the jacket UV map, the preview shows the jacket UV with the jacket UV on the sleeve.

Image1[image]

When I select the logo UV, the jacket will become transparent with a logo on the sleeve.

Image2[image]

It is successful to see both UV in the lighting shading mode.

Image3[image]

I am making an anime character with flat color so I don't know if it affects the final look if I use lighting mode. Although there are two different UV maps, the mesh of the sleeve shares the same area of both UV maps and I don't know how to separate them.

Image4[image]
Image5[image]
Image6[image]

Comment: Hm that shader tree looks correct. Maybe try different Alpha methods for your bear head texture. Otherwise, could you please do file > external data > pack all into file, save a new file with the *Compress* option on, and upload it on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and [edit] your question to add the download link please? So that we can check what's going on in your scene.

Comment: @L0Lock Not necessary to upload a file. Jess: You are using the _Texture_ option in the _Solid_ shading mode. This does not show combined textures, therefore you have to be in _Material Preview_ or _Rendered_ shading mode. How the _Texture_ in _Solid_ shading works I explain in more detail in my answer on this question: [UV Grid appearing as solid colour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296120/uv-grid-appearing-as-solid-colour)