# Why texture is seen?

Tags: image

[image]

I have 2 image texture but the below image texture is not connected and its .png transparent file. How the image is seen without connecting,

Comment: Maybe you are in Solid mode and in the Viewport Shading you need to select Color > Material instead of Texture (which will display the selected Image Texture)

Comment: My answer to this question here: [UV Grid appearing as solid colour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296120/uv-grid-appearing-as-solid-colour/296169#296169) explains in a bit more detail how the _Viewport Shading_ options in _Solid_ mode work... because I assume just as @moonboots does that you are using _Solid_ shading with the _Texture_ option.